# pointerEvents not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a list of the following elements :

```
<li id="toolbar-elements-right">
  <img id="toolbar-icons" src="images/delete_resource.png" alt="" title="Delete VM" onclick="removeNode()">
  <img id="toolbar-icons" src="images/power_off.png" alt="" title="Stop VM" onclick="changeInstanceStatus('Stop')">
  <img id="toolbar-icons" src="images/power_on.png" alt="" title="Start VM" onclick="changeInstanceStatus('Start')">
  <img id="toolbar-icons_zoom-in" src="images/zoom-in-icon.png" alt="" title="Zoom In" onclick="zoomNodeIn()">
  <img id="toolbar-icons_zoom-out" src="images/zoom-out-icon.png" alt="" title="Zoom Out" onclick="zoomNodeOut()">
</li>
```

I want the entire list to be disabled apart from the last two images in a function. I'm doing something like this :

```
  document.getElementById('toolbar-elements-right').style.pointerEvents = 'none';
  document.getElementById('toolbar-icons_zoom-in').style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
  document.getElementById('toolbar-icons_zoom-out').style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
```

However, the first element 'toolbar-icons_zoom-in'is enabled, but the second element 'toolbar-icons_zoom-out' remains disabled. Any way to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

You can instead disable the first items only. I have added a css class for the disabled elements and applied css via JavaScript.

```
<li id="toolbar-elements-right">
  <img class="disable-pointer" id="toolbar-icons" src="images/delete_resource.png" alt="" title="Delete VM" onclick="removeNode()">
  <img class="disable-pointer" id="toolbar-icons" src="images/power_off.png" alt="" title="Stop VM" onclick="changeInstanceStatus('Stop')">
  <img class="disable-pointer" id="toolbar-icons" src="images/power_on.png" alt="" title="Start VM" onclick="changeInstanceStatus('Start')">
  <img id="toolbar-icons_zoom-in" src="images/zoom-in-icon.png" alt="" title="Zoom In" onclick="zoomNodeIn()">
  <img id="toolbar-icons_zoom-out" src="images/zoom-out-icon.png" alt="" title="Zoom Out" onclick="zoomNodeOut()">
</li>
```

And the JS

```
var elem = document.querySelectorAll(".disable-pointer");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
    elem[i].style.pointerEvents = 'none';
}
```

If you prefer plain CSS, then that's much easier like doing

```
.disable-pointer {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It works in my case. Check your onClick function zoomNodeOut() if that is working.

https://jsfiddle.net/r110668L/

```
    <li id="toolbar-elements-right">
       <img id="toolbar-icons" style="width:100px; height:100px; background:#111; margin:5px;display: inline-block;" src="images/delete_resource.png" alt="" title="Delete VM" onclick="alert(1)">
       <img id="toolbar-icons" style="width:100px; height:100px; background:#111; margin:5px;display: inline-block;" src="images/power_off.png" alt="" title="Stop VM" onclick="alert(2)">
       <img id="toolbar-icons" style="width:100px; height:100px; background:#111; margin:5px;display: inline-block;" src="images/power_on.png" alt="" title="Start VM" onclick="alert(3)">
       <img id="toolbar-icons_zoom-in" style="width:100px; height:100px; background:#111; margin:5px;display: inline-block;" src="images/zoom-in-icon.png" alt="" title="Zoom In" onclick="alert(4)">
       <img id="toolbar-icons_zoom-out" style="width:100px; height:100px; background:#111; margin:5px;display: inline-block;" src="images/zoom-out-icon.png" alt="" title="Zoom Out" onclick="alert(5)">
   </li>
```

Note: There is a basic error in your HTML. You see the ID selector has to be unique in a page/DOM. You cannot have more than one element with same ID.

Comment: Yes, it is working now. I don't know why it wasn't working

Answer (score 2):

**DEMO:**

http://plnkr.co/edit/2g0hsfgeKRImzXbSPF1p?p=preview

It is working fine. Please check the demo.

```js
document.getElementById('toolbar-elements-right').style.pointerEvents = 'none';
document.getElementById('d').style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
document.getElementById('e').style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
```

```html
<div id="toolbar-elements-right">
  <div id="a" onclick="alert('a')">a</div>
  <div id="b" onclick="alert('b')">b</div>
  <div id="c" onclick="alert('c')">c</div>
  <div id="d" onclick="alert('d')">d</div>
  <div id="e" onclick="alert('e')">e</div>
</div>
```